# I Need a general-purpose note-taking software with organizational functionality

Tags: gratis, note-taking, cross-platform

I would like to take notes more efficiently and fluidly for general-purpose purposes that span to include notes about software, lists on PC parts, student notes etc.

I find that writing plain text and having it output something that is very nice and stylized to be quite efficient for my note-taking needs as a student. Thus, the software I need should have these features:

1. Cross-platform (or at least run on Windows 10)
2. Markdown support
3. Ability to create notebooks

   - This should also include the ability to create a notebook and group notes into folders/chapters. For example, I wanted to create a notebook called "Novel Notebook" and wanted to organize my notes into seperate folders like "Characters" and "Ideas".
4. Manage notes with tags
5. FREE <-- **IMPORTANT!** (preferably as in "free speech", i.e. open-source – but at least as in "free beer" (no money involved)

**UPDATE - 7.24.2018**: Found a software called Simplenote, however it doesn't seem to fit all the requirements as it lacks organizational functionality. I also found something called Laverna, but it is aimed towards programmers and I am not sure whether I should use it without a professional opinion.

Comment: You could try evernote

Comment: @cybernard it doesn't have Markdown support. I have looked into it before.

Answer (score 2):

After testing more than 300 software, the best I can recommend are:

- [onenote](http://www.onenote.com) is free and by microsoft, the best note taker I ever seen, it have all the features you mentioned above, you can add markdown support with addons like: [onenotegem](https://www.onenotegem.com/markdown.html) but i don t think you will need this, just test onenote and I think you will never look for other thing again.
- [zim-wiki](http://zim-wiki.org)  it is good too, free open source, and have markdown, that is what I was using before discovering onenote.
- [cherrytree](https://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/)  I like this one too, it is like zim-wiki
- [Nixnote](http://nixnote.org/NixNote-Home/) this is one is like evernote/onenote, but it is open source, and it understand better pasted html text from webs. A must have.
- [typora](https://typora.io/) this one is really nice, it is new
- [boostnote](https://boostnote.io) this one is new too and promising...
- and of course I cannot not mention [gitbook](https://www.gitbook.com/)

Comment: Typora is cool, supports code snippets and TeX equation out of the box (making those work in zim-wiki was _pain_). Does it support tags, though?

Comment: @Headcrab no it does not. I had read that onenote added tags in his last version for win 10...but only for win 10 :(

Comment: Typora is no longer free.